# How to search the web and display partial result using Java

Tags: java, google-custom-search, bing-api, web-search

I'm developing an app (Java) where I need to search the web based on a user's choice (eg. they choose films, then a random film name is suggested). Looking around I have found Google Custom Search API and Bing Search API; however I don't want to display a search box, neither all of the results, just a result name.   [in case of films: Movie databases haven't been helpful either, as I would need the film name/imdb id]

Is there any way I can do this for free and without breaking the ToS/T&C? (eg. the above do not allow results to be edited/truncated?!)

Comment: is there not an google random search function which might help you ?